# How to use PayPal payment gateway to charge customers in INR and absorb currency conversion cost

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

We are a canadian company and wants to sell products in India in INR, but when we transfer the price to PayPal PG, the value has to be shared in USD and PayPal charges the customer hefty on conversion increasing cost.

how can we either:
1) Absorb the conversion cost and charge customer the exact amount OR
2) Get PayPal conversion rate+commission and do reverse calculation to display the prices accordingly.

We tried various codes and all in vain

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: No @Rathinam :(